# Getting a class member name as a string

Tags: python, django

I have a python class (basically a Django serializer):

```
class UsersSerializer(serializers.Serializer): 
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=40)
    users = UserSerializerField(many=True)
```

When I use this serializer to serialize a REST request I have to do something like:

```
name = serializer.data.pop("name")
```

In order to get the name field of the serializer's data.

This creates a fragile coupling between the class itself and anywhere I use it.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
name = serializer.data.pop(serializer.name.__varname__)
```

This way, when refactoring, I will soon figure out there's this place I need to refactor as well. While with using a string, I won't be able to find it.

I know I can add a const to the serializer, but I would prefer to have something more elegant.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are doing here. Why is using an attribute better than using a dict key? And what is that varname supposed to be? And why do you want to pop it anyway?

Comment: How could `serializer.name` doesn't named `name`?

Comment: Or you mean `serializer.name.name`? `CharField` does have an attribute named `name`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - mainly for refactor reasons. Changing a class member easily finds it in all other places using tools like pycharm. While it would usually be hard to correlate a field name with a string in another file. Especially if that's a string like "name" which repeats itself in many places in the code.

Comment: What about `UsersSerializer.name.field_name` instead of `"name"`?